# we need to have flexibly to connect any salesforce org by entering user id and password (credentials )

Tags: rest-api, integration, soap-api, httpcalloutmock

there is a requirement in my project i.e.. we need to integrate the target salesforce org form source org (salesforce).

> in this process I have gone through many documents which are available in google where my findings are that we can do with the help of connected apps ..
> but the concern is with the connected app we can integrate with two orgs .. but in my project ***we need to have flexibly to connect any  salesforce org by entering user id and password (credentials ) ..***

help me to achieve this  task...

Answer (score 0):

> but the concern is with the connected app we can integrate with two orgs

This is not accurate. When you perform an OAuth connection to a Salesforce org, you supply a Connected App to define who *you* are: what's the name of your app, what identifies your app to the Salesforce platform, and what are the privileges you're requesting from the API.

A Connected App is *not* a tool for connecting two orgs. It is part of the OAuth authentication process for a client to access one or many Salesforce orgs.

> we need to have flexibly to connect any salesforce org by entering user id and password

Make sure you are using OAuth to establish a connection, and store the access and/or refresh tokens securely. **Never store raw credentials**, such as a username and password.